# iOS 8 kills Unwind Segues

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8, uistoryboardsegue

i'm having a problem getting my App ready for `iOS 8`.
Like it is stated in a lot of other questions modal unwind segues don't seem to work correctly anymore when compiling against the `iOS 8 SDK`.

While for there is a easy workaround for modally presented ViewControllers(aka `[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES]`), there is no such workaround for a Popover Exit Segue that does not involve adding a `UIPopoverController` Reference to the presented View Controller.

Since i'm using unwindSegue for all of my popover presented View Controllers I would really like to find a workaround(or a fix) for this, because I really don't want to add a `UIPopoverController` reference to all my presented ViewControllers just because of a bug in the iOS 8 SDK.

Anyone experienced something similar or does know an easy workaround?